# How to handle Exceptions in Apache CXF

Tags: web-services, cxf

**I'm using the CXF for developing webservices.**

But I was wondering what is Best Practice for handling exceptions? Let's say I have a webservice-operation, create(User user).
 The incoming user is an instance of my User domain class, and can be saved directly by  the UI Team by calling  user.save()

If the save() for some reason fail (e.g. some Network connectivity  fail , or some data validation error from User DTO ), how would Best Practice dictate that I serve this exception to the client?

I mean: Which type of Exception would be suitable?

Should this Exception be included in the operations signature ??

```
public Response createUser(User user);

@WebService
public interface EmpService {
public Response createUser(User user);
}
```

**And how should the client-side handle this exception?**

Comment: Are you asking whether the exception details will be in the `response` ? or threw a separate exception like this `public Response createUser(User user) throws MyOwnUserException;`

Answer (score 0):

One company I was working in, with web services had almost 15 years of experience, so I have learned some things. We handled the exception simply by specified `throws` statement in the method. And if some expected error occurred, we just simply constructed the exception and throw it with the message which pointing to reason why something has failed.

The client should handle all exceptions thrown by service in anyway he likes to do it. If you are developing a web service, you need to be worried about how to correctly create an exception with appropriate reason in it. And when exception occurs the client will see it anyway.